# How to assert in a JPM test

Tags: unit-testing, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, assert, jpm

My synthetic test:

```
exports.testAssertObject = function(assert) {
    console.log(arguments);
    assert.ok(assert, "Assert object exists");
};
```

fails in JPM with `TypeError: assert.ok is not a function`:

```
$jpm --version
0.0.29
$jpm test
JPM undefined Starting jpm test on Reuse Tab
Creating XPI
JPM undefined XPI created at ...\AppData\Local\Temp\jid1-K8e1vROHVMoXWQ@jetpack-0.6.1.xpi (327ms)
Created XPI at ...\AppData\Local\Temp\jid1-K8e1vROHVMoXWQ@jetpack-0.6.1.xpi
JPM undefined Creating a new profile
Running tests on Firefox 38.0a2/Gecko 38.0a2 ({ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}) under winnt/x86.
console.log: reusetab: {"0":{"console":{},"passed":0,"failed":0,"testRunSummary":[],"expectFailNesting":0,"test":{"name":"./test/test-utils.testAssertObject","passed":0,"failed":0,"errors":{},"last":"START"},"isDone":false,"waitTimeout":null}}
console.error: reusetab: 
JPM undefined   Message: ReferenceError: assert is not defined
  Stack:
    exports.testAssertObject@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://jid1-k8e1vrohvmoxwq-at-jetpack/test/test-utils.js:3:2
start@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/deprecated/unit-test.js:559:7
startMany/runNextTest/<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/deprecated/unit-test.js:522:11
Handler.prototype.process@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:867:23
this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:746:7
this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:688:37



0 of 1 tests passed.
There were test failures...
```

I assume, that [unlike cfx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Unit_testing), jpm does not pass [assert object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/test_assert) as test method argument?

How do I implement assertion and [notify "done" in async tests](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Unit_Testing/1.1#Asynchronous_tests)?

Answer (score 2):

JPM (like cfx) does not run tests with the assert method by default, but instead rubs them using an older version of the test harness. All you need to do to use the current test harness is add

```
require("sdk/test").run(exports);
```

to your trsts files, as documented on the Unit Testing page you linked.

Answer (score 1):

To get updated list of assert methods, read

resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/deprecated/unit-test.js

First argument of test method is TestRuner object implemented in this resource and  has a different interface:

In particular:

- `ok()` method is replaced with `assert()`
- `throws()` is replaced with `assertRaises(func, predicate, message)` (different signature)
- `equal()` is replaced with `assertEqual()`, many other method are also prefixed with "assert"
- `done()` method now belongs to TestRunner too (no second argument for your test method) to declare your method async call `waitUntilDone(timeoutInMs)` on TestRunner